# How to use Jquery Mask Money for each table cell on specific column?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, mask

I would like to implement [Jquery Mask Money](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney) inside each table cell on a specific column. Below is the code that i'm trying to implement as i would like:

**HTML Table Code**

```
<script src="js/jquery.maskMoney.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
  <table id="users_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Beer</td>
    <td ><input type="text" id="price" value="94"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Bread</td>
    <td ><input type="text" id="price" value="34"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>

<script>
  $('#users_data tr').each(function() {

 $("#price").maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: false, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: true});

});
  </script>
```

The code above display table with respective data but the MaskMoney plugin just works inside first cell. I tried jquery each.() function to do this but no response. In this case how can i improve my code to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery selectors `#` denotes an `id`. There can be only one control with that `id` value on the page. So you either need to have unique `id`'s or use `class` attributes. `Class` attributes are usually the way to go.

```
 <tr>
     <td>Jill</td>
     <td>Beer</td>
     <td ><input type="text" id="price-1" class="price" value="94"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Eve</td>
     <td>Bread</td>
     <td ><input type="text" id="price-2" class="price" value="34"></td>
 </tr>
```

And for your js `$("#price")` simply gets changed to `$(".price")` as the `.` tells jQuery to look for controls with a class attribute called 'price'.

Comment: ...Not sure why this has been down voted

Comment: Thanks, Sean. I solved the problem based on your answer. I dont know why moderator down voted your answer :/. Thanks a lot.